# "select user()" is executed before every SQL

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat, select

i make my best to find the answer: why "select user()" is executed before every SQLs.
i try two way to create dataSource, and thend use same way to use the dataSource, and then execute my SQLs. 
config 1 will execute "select user()" before every SQL.
config 2 is right, just execute what i wanted.

## config 1:

### tomcat#conf#server.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxIdle="10" maxTotal="100" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="10000"  
numTestsPerEvictionRun="10" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="10" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://dbserver:3306/***" 
username="***"  password="***" name="jdbc/tomcatDataSource" validationQuery="SELECT NOW() FROM DUAL"/>
```

### WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>tomcatDataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/tomcatDataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

### spring config

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/tomcatDataSource" />
</bean>
```

## config 2: spring config

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property> 
    <property name="url"><value>jdbc:mysql://dbserver:3306/***</value></property> 
    <property name="username"><value>***</value></property> 
    <property name="password"><value>***</value></property> 
</bean>
```

Comment: use config 2, and change class to org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource. then i got config 1's result. is dbcp's problem? (tomcat use dbcp too). if i just chang to other class(ex: druid) all results is ok